# Proving size of a collection of ordered pairs of disjoint subsets using bijection

Tags: combinatorics

I've been having a lot of trouble with this problem.

> Let $n \ge 0$ be an integer and let $S_0$ be the collection of ordered pairs of disjoint subsets of $\{1, . . . , n\} = [n]$; that is,
>   $$
> S_0 = \{(A, B) : A \subseteq [n], B \subseteq [n], A \cap B = \emptyset\}.
> $$
>
> Show using a bijection that $|S_0| = 3^n$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You would get a better response if you included what you have tried and what exactly you have a problem with in the body of your question. It would also makes it easier for us to guide you. For starters, I included a hint in my answer, please feel free to change your question or post comments to the answer with your further work on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Since $A \cap B = \emptyset$, think about picking a typical element $(A,B) \in S_0$. For each integer $k \in \{1, \ldots n\}$, you can

- put it in $A$, but not in $B$
- put it in $B$, but not in $A$
- don't use it at all

This gives you a set of 3 choices, first labeled as $a$, second as $b$, third as $x$. Now you have a bijection from the number of elements of $S_0$ to the number of strings of length $n$ from the alphabet $\{a,b,x\}$.

Can you finish?